# Gson-Object has null values when subclass attempts to use it after deserialization

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson, android

I have a GatewayModel class into which the json string is de-serialized using GSON. This is done correctly .

```
public class GatewayModel  {

    private String title;
    private String body;
    protected Common common;
    private ArrayList<Gateway1> gateways;
    private Note note;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ArrayList<Gateway1> getGateways() {
        return gateways;
    }

    public void setGateways(ArrayList<Gateway1> gateways) {
        this.gateways = gateways;
    }

    public Common getCommon() {
        return common;
    }

    public void setCommon(Common common) {
        this.common = common;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Note getNote() {

        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(Note note) {
        this.note = note;
    }
}
```

SUBCLASS

```
 public class Gateway  extends GatewayModel implements Serializable {

        private String name;
        private String image;
        private String button;
        private Form form;
        private Self self;

        private transient ArrayList<Element> preparedElements = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
        * Prepares elements from json - rejects invalid elements & adds common elements
        * */
        public ArrayList<Element> prepareGatewayData() {

            ArrayList<Element> elements = this.getForm().getElements();
            ArrayList<Element> elementsPrepared = new ArrayList<>();

            if (elements == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Common common=this.getCommon();//NULL VALUE 
    //        elements.addAll(getCommon().getElement());

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {/
                Element element = elements.get(i);

                if (element.hasValidType()) {
                    elementsPrepared.add(element);
                }
    //
            }
            this.setPreparedElements(elementsPrepared);

            return elementsPrepared;

        }
    }
```

> The value of GatewayModel.common obj (super class) is returned as
>   null from subclass (Gateway) even when GatewayModel.common has correct
>   value when accessed from GatewayModel.

**Gson deserialization**

```
  GatewayModel gatewayModel = null;
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        try {
                            gatewayModel = gson.fromJson(response.getResponse(), GatewayModel.class);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (gatewayModel != null && gatewayModel.getGateways() != null) {
                            gatewaysList=gatewayModel.getGateways();
                        }
```

[image]

I'm not sure if this is gson issue or inheritance issue. I have referred to

[Object has null values when subclass attempts to use it. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404404/object-has-null-values-when-subclass-attempts-to-use-it-why)

**EDIT**

Here is the json

```
{
  "title": "Deposit",
  "body": "Deposits are credited immediately  ",
  "common": {
    "elements": {
      "national_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "National ID",
        "rules": "required",
        "value": ""
      },
      "terms_and_condition": {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "I understand that third party deposit is not allowed, ",
        "rules": "required",
        "value": ""
      },
      "button": {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "Next Step",
        "rules": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "gateways": [
    {
      "name": "R",
      "image": "https://*******/Rfupay.png",
      "button": "Deposit",
      "form": {
        "title": "R - payment gateway",
        "body": {
          "p": [
            "Processing fee: w!!",
            "Withdrawal fee: No fees enk",
            "Transaction limits: minimum $0 per transaction, "
          ]
        },
        "url": "https://****/api/v1/deposit/gateways/16",
        "method": "POST",
        "elements": {
          "amount": {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Amount",
            "rules": "required|numeric|between:0,150000",
            "value": ""
          },
          "currency_type": {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Currency",
            "rules": "required",
            "value": "",
            "options": {
              "USD": "USD"
            }
          },
          "bank_id": {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Bank Name",
            "value": "",
            "options": {
              "0011": " Agricultural Bank ",

            },
            "rules": "required|in:00017,00021,00004,00003,00032,00013,00016,00005,00057,00083,00006,00051,00054,00041"
          },
          "card_type": {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Card Type",
            "value": "",
            "options": {
              "01": " debit card"
            },
            "rules": "required|in:01"
          },
          "national_id": "common.elements.national_id",
          "terms_and_condition": "common.elements.terms_and_condition",
          "button": "common.elements.button"
        }
      },
      "self": {
        "url": "https://******/api/v1/deposit/gateways/16",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    },

    {
      "name": "A",
      "image": "https://*****/assets/images/AlgoCharge.png",
      "button": "Deposit",
      "form": {
        "title": "A - payment gateway",
        "body": {
          "p": [
            "Processing fee: 4%,!",
            "Withdrawal fee: No fees k",
            "Transaction limits: minimum $0 per transaction,"
          ]
        },
        "url": "https://***/api/v1/deposit/gateways/10",
        "method": "POST",
        "elements": {
          "amount": {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Amount",
            "rules": "required|numeric|between:0,150000",
            "value": ""
          },
          "currency_type": {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Currency",
            "rules": "required",
            "value": "",
            "options": {
              "USD": "USD"
            }
          },
          "national_id": "common.elements.national_id",
          "terms_and_condition": "common.elements.terms_and_condition",
          "button": "common.elements.button"
        }
      },
      "self": {
        "url": "https://*********/api/v1/deposit/gateways/10",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "S",
      "image": "https://*****/assets/images/Skrill.png",
      "button": "Deposit",
      "form": {
        "title": "S - payment gateway",
        "body": {
          "p": [
            "Processing fee: 3%, !!",
            "Withdrawal fee: No fees ",
            "Transaction limits: minimum $0 per transaction,"
          ]
        },
        "url": "https://*****/api/v1/deposit/gateways/11",
        "method": "POST",
        "elements": {
          "amount": {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Amount",
            "rules": "required|numeric|between:0,150000",
            "value": ""
          },
          "currency_type": {
            "type": "select",
            "label": "Currency",
            "rules": "required",
            "value": "",
            "options": {
              "USD": "USD"
            }
          },
          "national_id": "common.elements.national_id",
          "terms_and_condition": "common.elements.terms_and_condition",
          "button": "common.elements.button"
        }
      },
      "self": {
        "url": "https://******/api/v1/deposit/gateways/11",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    }
  ],
  "note": {
    "title": "Note:",
    "body": [
      "Priority card deposit and redemption services will resume by 01 August 2016",
      "Master/Visa service is not applicable to card issues by banks of ."
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

some changes in the values of some strings i json , cant share the exact json string , it would not comply with my company norms

Comment: Please add the JSON you parse. Or response.

Comment: @xenteros added json

Comment: Paste it to the question. You can use code formatting. On [so] we don't rely on external storage.

Comment: @xenteros done pls check

Comment: The GSON doesn't have a gateway with name Rfupay. You display another object's values in the picture.

Comment: @xenteros made some changes in the values of some strings i json , cant share the exact json string , it would not comply with my company norms